# Change GCC's output for 0-set (clear) operation

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

GCC often produces the following x86 assembly to set the value in `eax` to 0 before returning to the caller:

```
xor eax, eax
```

For the purposes of *can I do it?*, as opposed to *should I do it?*, is it possible to change GCC's behaviour to produce "equivalent" assembly? Also, where in libgcc does this generation occur?

To clarify, I'm not looking for guidance on which assembly instructions would be appropriate to use, I'm wondering how it is possible to change GCC's output behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You mean like `sub eax,eax` which is specially recognized as a zeroing idiom on only some CPUs, not all?

The optimization is done as part of `-fpeephole2`, as part of `-O2` or `-Os`; using `-fno-peephole2` would give you `mov eax,0` for materializing a `0` in a register.  (As well as creating other missed optimizations I assume!  xor-zeroing probably isn't the only peephole gcc looks for.)

I don't know where to look in the gcc source code but knowing the option might help track it down.

It's not in "libgcc" though, that's helper functions like 64-bit multiply on a 32-bit machine.  (When gcc emits calls to funny-named helper functions like [`__udivdi3`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Integer-library-routines.html), it's expecting the asm output to be linked against libgcc).

More like you'd find it in the x86 machine-definition files, one of the `.md` files in the gcc source tree.  Otherwise hard-coded into a C optimization function.  Like `"xor %1, %0"` might be something to search on, or more likely it'll have `{... | ...}` dialect-alternatives.  But searching on the `xor` mnemonic might still help.

#### This is a half-assed partial answer.  Please post a specific answer or at least leave a comment if you know where to look.

Comment: I found a relevant x86 tuning option [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/e1f7ba02d1279f97ed6673714f41316c513c8894/gcc/config/i386/x86-tune.def#L536), but can't find where it is acted upon.

Comment: Found it! [Here's the generation function](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/i386-expand.c#L150).

Comment: gcc/config/i386/i386.md, around line 1884, "*mov<mode>_xor" (there are others for different types / circumstances).